# How to disable the click on overlay to close Colorbox?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp-2.0, colorbox

I want to prevent colorbox close on cboxOverlay click

I'm using this code:

```
$.fn.colorbox({ overlayClose: false });
```

But it doesn't  work.

I also disabled <kbd>Esc</kbd> close

```
$(document).bind("keydown.cbox_close", function (e) {

        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
               e.preventDefault();
               cboxPublic.close();
            }});
```

Esc code working properly .

But how to prevent colorbox close for overlay?

Thanks

Comment: :) i found 

$(".ajax").colorbox({overlayClose: false});

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
$.colorbox({ overlayClose: false });
```

See working demo here: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aanred/DSXHt/)**